# Execute Dynamically loaded javascript Windows Store App

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm currently developing a C#/xaml app using the WindowsRT/Metro framework

Is there any way in Windows Store Apps to load and run javascript from a string? I'm looking to use Javascript in a similar way Game Engines would invoke LUA/Python scripts to perform dynamic functionality without recompiling the engine. It seems IOS can achieve this using JavascriptCore

We're currently using javascript on other platforms to perform some simple logic at various stages of a workflow (e.g. User configured behaviour in a form or wizard such as populating fields based on already entered data). Ideally at certain points in the workflow I would like to be able to invoke a javascript function which had access to a simple API already defined in the application.

Is this currently possible on Windows Store apps?

The app will not be deployed on the normal Windows Store but rather used only in enterprise type deployments

Answer (score 1):

load the html from the local file using webview.navigatetostring then you can inject the javascript and from with in the app you can use invoke script to call a function

go through the link below
[Invoke script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript.aspx)

but i really would like to know how you would like to distribute the app for enterprise purpose. I dont think that might be possible. Please explain.

Comment: We're current planning to distribute through enterprise sideloading, we'll have full access to the domain we're deploying into. I've had a look at using invoke script but it doesn't help in terms of invoking the C# code in a way like Iron Python could, just to clarify the app is completely C# XAML based, I'm just looking for a way to add some dynamic post processing on some of the objects edited by the application

Comment: Wait for some time i am using my tab to clarify your doubts once i get to the machine ill explain all. Till then please tell me wether you are using/developing a c# xaml application. And it is a metro app . Ie the one to run in surface tablets ????

Comment: Question edited to clarify, yes I am currently using C#/Xaml. What I'm looking for is basically JavascriptCore for IOS

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 restricts use of dynamic code (injecting Dynamic HTML).
You can possibly look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767331.aspx)
Run JavaScript from a string : you can use eval() function